# NSPredicate and arrays

Tags: cocoa, arrays, nspredicate

I've got a short question. I have an `NSArray` filled with `Cars` (which inherits from NSObject).  `Car` has the `@property NSString *engine` (also regarded `@synthesize`)

Now I want to filter the array using `NSPredicate`:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(engine like %@)", searchText]];
newArray = [ArrayWithCars filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This throws an `valueForUndefinedKey` error.  Is the `predicateWithFormat` correct?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the real reason why it's not working:

When you build a string using `stringWithFormat:`, it's going to come up looking like this:

```
@"engine like searchText"
```

You then pass it to `predicateWithFormat:`, which is going to see that both the lefthand side and the righthand side of the comparison are *unquoted* strings, which means it's going to interpret them as if they were *keypaths*.

When this code runs, it's going to be doing:

```
id leftValue = [object valueForKey:@"engine"];
id rightValue = [object valueForKey:@"searchText"];
return (leftValue is like rightValue);
```

The exception getting thrown is your object complaining that it doesn't have a method named "searchText", which is correct.

Contrast this to if you took out the `stringWithFormat:` call and just put everything directly into `predicateWithFormat:`:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"engine like %@", searchText];
```

`predicateWithFormat:` is smart.  It sees "aha, a `%@` replacement pattern! this means I can pop an argument off the argument list and box it up and use it as-is".  That's exactly what it's going to do.  It's going to pop the value of `searchText` off the argument list, box it in an `NSExpression`, and insert it directly into the parsed expression tree.

What's most interesting here is that the expression it creates will be a *constant value* expression.  This means it's a literal value; not a key path, not a collection, etc.  It will be the literal string.  Then when your predicate runs, it's going to do:

```
id leftValue = [object valueForKey:@"engine"];
id rightValue = [rightExpression constantValue];
return (leftValue is like rightValue);
```

And *that* is correct, and is also why you should not pass stuff through `stringWithFormat:` before passing it to `predicateWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 3):

k, I found the mistake.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"engine like *%@*", searchText];
```

works correct. The ** were missing. Additionally your searchText should be uppercase.

@Josuhua
this is no real code, just to visualize my problem

Comment: bend0r: Don't case-fold strings; when you need to compare strings case-insensitively, use case-insensitive comparison. In this case, that's `LIKE[c]`.

Comment: Posting code other than that which you're using usually doesn't help others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is more verbose than necessary, which always opens you up to the possibility that it's wrong. Try:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"engine like %@", searchText];
```

Second, "ArrayWithCars" looks like a class name (by convention, classes begin with upper-case). Is it actually a class or an improperly-named local variable (ex: "arrayWithCars" or just "cars")?

Third, what is the exact error? What key is undefined? Don't paraphrase errors when asking others for help - we can't see what you're seeing unless you show us.

Comment: Correct.  The inclusion of `stringWithFormat:` is what was causing the problem.  See my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this [link.](http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/09/nspredicate-with-object.html)You may know different ways of using **NSPredicate**