# NSPredicate on array of arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an array, that when printed out looks like this:

```
(
        (
        databaseVersion,
        13
    ),
        (
        lockedSetId,
        100
    )
)
```

Would it be possible to filter this using an `NSPredicate` (potentially by the index in the array). So something like: give me all rows where element 0 is 'databaseVersion'? I know that if I had an array of dictionaries I could do this with a predicate similar the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506836/nspredicate-and-arrays), but I found that when using dictionaries and storing a large amount of data, my memory consumption went up (from ~80mb to ~120mb), so if possible I would to keep the array. Any suggestions on how this might be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using "SELF[index]" in the predicate:

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @[@"databaseVersion", @13],
    @[@"lockedSetId", @100],
    @[@"databaseVersion", @55],
    @[@"foo", @"bar"]
];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[0] == %@", @"databaseVersion"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

*Output:*

```
(
        (
        databaseVersion,
        13
    ),
        (
        databaseVersion,
        55
    )
)
```

Or you can use a block-based predicate:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSArray *elem, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [elem[0] isEqualTo:@"databaseVersion"];
}];
```

Comment: Ah very nice. That does exactly what i'm looking for. Just curious where you came up with the `SELF[index]` value. I'm not seeing that anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: @Zenox it's defined in the BNF for predicate format strings: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-217950

Answer (score 6):

Simply you can use **ANY** in NSPredicate:

it's works fine

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", @"value"];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF contains[cd] %@", @"value"];
```