# NSPredicate on array of arrays where some empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, nspredicate

I'm attempting to filter an array of arrays which contains a core data entity of type Bird. The entities have been split into arrays of arrays based on a UITableView with sections and rows.

To search I have the following method based on this question [NSPredicate on array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767516/nspredicate-on-array-of-arrays):

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF[0].common_name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
    self.filteredBirds = self.birds.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate!)
}
```

This however results in the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

which probably makes sense because the array has 27 (A-Z, #) elements of which some have no entities

So, how can I adjust the NSPredicate query to take into consideration some arrays maybe empty?

Comment: Why do you have the empty arrays? Are they useful? Get rid of them. The other answer you refer to is a different problem, you don't want to index into the array, you want to check the full array contents...

Comment: There are empty arrays because UILocalizedIndexedCollation generates the array of indexes (A-Z, #) based on the users locale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re interested in a stronger-typed filtering operation, and you’re using the latest Xcode 6.3, you can use `flatMap`, which will perform a mapping operation that returns arrays on an array of arrays, and flattens the result.  Then you can use filter in the subarrays:

```
// assuming birds is an NSArray containing NSArrays of Bird
if let arrayOfArrays = birds as? [[Bird]] {
    let filteredBirds = arrayOfArrays.flatMap { birds in
        birds.filter { bird in
            bird.common_name.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.@count >0  AND SELF[0].common_name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
```

Comment: Please provide context with your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Adding the count did get around the empty array issue but @AirspeedVelocity answer did solve the root of the problem to filter an array of arrays.

Comment: `@count` did help me!